# Display icons and name of application for iphone application

Tags: iphone

How i can display all applications icons and name which are installed in device in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not have the relevant APIs for that. I am not sure if SDK 4 will allow that, but as it is still under NDA, you will not be able to find out unless you are a registered developer. If you are a registered developer, use the Apple Developer Forums to ask other members.